# How to combine two reports

Tags: reporting

I have two reports "Lead history" and "Lead Activity history" which I want to join  using joined reports. If I try to join theses reports,I am unable to find common fields between them as a result I get the error "Incompatible Report Type
This report type cannot be used, because it has no fields in common with the report types in your joined report.".

How to implement this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  I can't wrap my head around joining a history report w another report type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to be possible the way you defined it

- Lead History report primary object is Lead History
- Lead Activity History report primary object is Task (Activity)

Hence, no common object to join

Because there is no common object, but a conceptual common `Lead.Id`, you might be better off writing a simple APEX VF controller and VF page to do the joins in memory into a single wrapper class.  You'll need to think about what your layout is going to look like as for a given lead, there are n field histories and m activities